# Everyone's talking about the same [dialogue]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[dialog](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dialog) and [dialogbox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dialogbox) are defined and synonomized.  [dialogue](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dialogue) is undefined and had one question.  I edited the tag to change it to [dialog], which leaves [dialogue] empty.  If the alternate spelling is important to keep, this can be synonomized.  Otherwise, it can be closed/deleted.

Comment: Catchy question title: Everyone's talking about the same [dialogue]

Comment: I think it'll be fine for this tag to fade into oblivion :)

Comment: Status is completed; requires moderator to add the tag